# How to combine top and bin in splunk query

Tags: splunk

I need to find abnormalities in my data. The data I have is individual views for certain movie titles. I need to find content that was abnormally popular over some small time interval, say 1 hour. And check a few weeks worth of data.

One option is to run a query manually for each hour

````
``` Run this over 60m time window ```
index=mydata 
| top limit=100 movieId
````

Obviously I don't want to do this 24 * 7 = 168 times for one weeks worth of data.

How can I bin the data into time buckets, and get a percentage ratio by movieId? This is what I came up with:

````
``` Run this over 1+ week ```
index=mydata
| bin span=60m _time
| top limit=100 movieId, _time
````

This does not help me because the output of `top` is showing me a percentage based on the entire input set of data. I need a "local" percentage, i.e. a percentage based on only that slice of data in the bin.

Answer (score 0):

To restate, you are using top to generate a percentage. However, you want that percentage calculated and viewed per unit of time. The SPL below is a run anywhere example, that has inline comments explaining each line. The logic you're looking for comes after the line with the bin command. It results in a percentage per hour per movie.

`````
| gentimes start=9/1/23 end=9/27/23 increment=5m 
| eval _time = starttime 
| eval ViewCount = random()%100 
| eval Movie = random()%5 
| eval MovieName = "Movie". "-" .Movie 
| fields _time MovieName ViewCount
     ```` everything above is to generate the random data needed for 5 movie examples over various time stamps ``` 
| bin _time span=1h ``` break down _time into one hour bins ``` 
| eventstats sum(ViewCount) AS SumCount BY _time ``` Add an event to the data that sums up all the view counts within those _time bins ``` 
| eval Pct = round('ViewCount'/'SumCount'*100,1) ``` Each movie now has its own count and carries a summary figure. We calculate a percentage and round it to one decimal place ``` 
| timechart span=1h sum(Pct) BY MovieName ``` To compare movie percentages in one hour spans of time (matches your bin span) ```
`````